# Mi programa se cierra al instante que clickeo para abrirlo

Tags: c++, vscode

Hice mi primer *Hola, Mundo!* en C++ usando VScode; mi problema es que no sé por qué cuando voy a la carpeta en mi escritorio y abro la aplicación del programa, éste se cierra al instante que clickeo para abrirlo.

He visto que usan `cin.get();` lo usé y sigue sin funcionar.

```
// Primer hello
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
    return 0;
    std::get.char();
}
```

Este es el código, ya coloqué el `using namespace std` para no ponérselo en la instrucción que me señaló un usuario, pero me sale error que debo declarar la variable `get`.

Comment: Elimina el `return 0;`. Este impide que se ejecute el get.char.

Comment: Sin necesidad de usar `get.char()`, puedes ejecutar el programa desde la consola, de esta forma verás la salida sin que se cierre la ventana de la consola. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El comando `return` indica el fin de la función, así que lo que venga después no se va a ejecutar nunca.
Pon la línea `get.char()` encima del `return`.

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó :)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que recuerdo de la facultad yo nunca use 'std::get.char()' para solucionar tu problema en particular, ya que por lo que tengo entendido get.char() se utiliza para capturar el valor de un input y lo almacena como tipo int.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdio/getchar

Por otro lado como ya mencionaron el return 0 siempre es la ultima línea de código, con ella finaliza la ejecución.

Por ultimo usábamos System("pause"); justo antes de return ya que sino el programa se ejecuta y se cierra ni bien termina de leer las instrucciones, pero como comenta Pablochaches funciona solo en Windows. No sabría cual usar en Linux ya que por lo que leí depende de cada tipo de terminal de Linux.

En este foro hay una persona con tu mismo problema y tampoco le funciono cin.get() pero le funciono el siguiente comando, te copio todo el código por las dudas:

Pause Command:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Enter to exit the program: ";

cin.ignore().get(); //Pause Command for Linux Terminal

return 0;
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: El comando `pause` es exclusivo de windows, el puede estar trabajando en linux o mac.